# Does Aysncpro 2010 have Memory Leak?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, serial-port, delphi-2010, delphi-prism

I have been using Aysncpro 2010 since my recent software update. The more I read about it online the more I am concerned it is probably leaking memory in my software and causing it to crash eventually. My software supposed to be communicating 24/7/365 for end of time, unless the computer dies or power outages.

Are there any alternatives that are equally good as Aysncpro 2010 without any major bugs for Delphi Prism and Delphi RAD XE?

Thanks,

Comment: Guessing is never a good option, instead use something that can detect a leak.    Then you will know if the problem is really in Apro or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416046/what-is-the-best-tool-to-detect-memory-leaks-in-delphi

Comment: "Probably" is no reason for switching components!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Prism, the SerialPort class should have everything you need. (Framework class)

Comment: @Ck, I see that in my ToolBox list and have used it. It works perfectly, but it doesn't have other options like Packet control and LED to display on the screen. I also want to replace Asyncpro 2010 for my Delphi RAD XE with a different serial communication tool. I believe Aysncpro 2010 is leaking memory and causing my software to crash.

Comment: Since Delphi XE is native and Delphi Prism is .NET, you won't find one thing that fits both. In fact, there aren't any other Serial port access libraries in the .NET world I would know about.