# How to monitor or visualize memory fragmentation of a delphi application

Tags: delphi, memory, heap-fragmentation

How can I monitor or visualize memory fragmentation of a delphi application?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most Delphi applications use [FastMM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fastmm/) now, and if you have the source code version linked in you can use the FastMMUsageTracker.pas file which creates a separate window showing how memory is used updated every second or so.

I took the code in that file and created a version which logs to file, so that I could use it in a service, but for a desktop app that standard tracker will work well.

Comment: @mj2008 FastMMUsageTracker.pas is all I need. Thanks for the quick response.