# Which is better using Record or Class as a value of TDictionary/TObjectDictionary in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'm making my own data structure in Delphi.
By the way, I'm faced with a problem that using between `record` and `class` as a value of dictionary.

Here's my code.

```
TContinuousItem = Record
    Count: Integer;
    Order: Integer;
    ContractTime: String;
end;

...

var 
    FItems: TDictionary<Integer, TContinuousItem>;
```

Below is using class.

```
TContinuousItem = class(TObject)
private
    FCount: Integer;
    FOrder: Integer;
    FContractTime: String;
public
    property Count: String read FCount;
    property Order: String read FOrder;
    property ContractTime: String read FContractTime;
    constructor Create(const count, order: Integer; const contractTime: String);
end;

...

var 
    FItems: TObjectDictionary<Integer, TContinuousITem>;
```

Requirements:

- Need to sort by `order` value of `record`/`class`
- Easy to use.
- Use less memory.

Which way is better to use? And what is more correct?

Comment: The answer is that it depends. Sometimes you want a value type, sometimes a reference type. Impossible to give a single recommendation. It all depends on how you want to work with this type.

Comment: If it needs to be sorted then `TDictionary` is not the right thing for you.

Comment: Here you can read about *less memory usage* point http://stackoverflow.com/q/1983506/960757. The rest really depends. For instance, if you were storing records in a *fixed collection* and sorting do in a list of pointers to the items of that collection (references), then records might be the way (since you would be sorting only references). Sorting a collection of records is inefficient as it performs memory re-allocation. Manipulation is also more difficult as you need to get copy of the record, modify it, and return that copy to the collection (which you don't need when using references).

Comment: @TLama Sorting values doesn't need any reallocation. Manipulation in a collection of value types can be awkward. We need C++ or D references. On the other hand sometimes value assignment is what you want.