# Benchmark Tools For Delphi

Tags: delphi, benchmarking

I'm looking for some tools to improve my Delphi development.
And a tool that I could not found any free project is a benchmark tool.

Some one have some hit about some project to use ?

Today to check where I must focus my optimizations I use sample profiling, but it's not enough 
I must file the function that spent more time overage, not just the top called functions.

Tks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the acknowledged leader in this field is [AQtime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/).

If you have no money then you can try [Sampling Profiler](http://delphitools.info/samplingprofiler/).

I'm sure others will be along in due course to offer yet more suggestions!

Comment: +1 for AQTime.  If you're using Delphi XE, you'll get a free but limited copy of it.

Comment: @jachguate Of course, the OP states that money is an issue so XE and AQtime may be a step too far. But AQtime is still awesome!!

Comment: We don't know which version of Delphi are @SaCi using, so it still an option for him.  The information is also valid for the rest of SO visitors.

Comment: @jach Indeed! I certainly wasn't attempting to criticise your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Check out my question on [Profiler and Memory Analysis Tools for Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291631/profiler-and-memory-analysis-tools-for-delphi).  In my Addenum 4, I mention André's Open Source Profiler for Delphi called AsmProfiler that he made. See [his answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291631/profiler-and-memory-analysis-tools-for-delphi/672554#672554) that led me to it.

I had downloaded it and tried it and it is quite good. It is an instrumenting profiler like AQTime, so it may be better than a Sampling Profiler for certain optimizations. It does procedure-based timings, so the one thing it can't do that AQTime is line-by-line based timings. But for a free program that works well, most often procedure-based timings are good enough. I had used GpProfile very productively for many years which was very similar but it is no longer available for current versions of Delphi.

Comment: Thanks for your positive answer :-). It is already an old project. My AsmProfiler has both an instrumenting and a sampling profiler. And the instrumenting profiler stores the time of each call (!) so it can make full trace too! Or a call history (!). See some screenshots: http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/wiki/AsmProfilerInstrumentingScreenshots