# How to Start Creating My Own Classes with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, oop, class

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270972/declare-locally-or-globally-in-delphi) a few days ago, and the answers told me to create my own classes.

I'm an old-school programmer from the pre-OOP days my programming is well structured, efficient and organized, but lacks in any custom OOPing other than using Delphi and 3rd party objects.

I had looked at how Delphi's object oriented classes worked back when I started using Delphi 2, but they seemed foreign to my programming background. I understand how they were and are excellent for developers designing components and for visual controls on the user interface. But I never found the need to use them in the coding of my program itself.

So now I look again, 15 years later, at Delphi's classes and OOPing. If I take, for example, a structure that I have such as:

```
type
  TPeopleIncluded = record
    IndiPtr: pointer;
    Relationship: string;
  end;
var
  PeopleIncluded: TList<TPeopleIncluded>;
```

Then an OOP advocator will probably tell me to make this a class. Logically, I would think this would be a class inherited from the generic TList. I would guess this would be done like this:

```
TPeopleIncluded<T: class> = class(TList<T>)
```

But that's where I get stuck, and don't have good instructions on how ot do the rest.

When I look at some class that Delphi has as an example in the Generics.Collections unit, I see:

```
TObjectList<T: class> = class(TList<T>)
private
  FOwnsObjects: Boolean;
protected
  procedure Notify(const Value: T; Action: TCollectionNotification); override;
public
  constructor Create(AOwnsObjects: Boolean = True); overload;
  constructor Create(const AComparer: IComparer<T>; AOwnsObjects: Boolean = True); overload;
  constructor Create(Collection: TEnumerable<T>; AOwnsObjects: Boolean = True); overload;
  property OwnsObjects: Boolean read FOwnsObjects write FOwnsObjects;
end;
```

and then their definitions of the constructors and procedures are:

```
{ TObjectList<T> }

constructor TObjectList<T>.Create(AOwnsObjects: Boolean);
begin
  inherited;
  FOwnsObjects := AOwnsObjects;
end;

constructor TObjectList<T>.Create(const AComparer: IComparer<T>; AOwnsObjects: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(AComparer);
  FOwnsObjects := AOwnsObjects;
end;

constructor TObjectList<T>.Create(Collection: TEnumerable<T>; AOwnsObjects: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(Collection);
  FOwnsObjects := AOwnsObjects;
end;

procedure TObjectList<T>.Notify(const Value: T; Action: TCollectionNotification);
begin
  inherited;
  if OwnsObjects and (Action = cnRemoved) then
    Value.Free;
end;
```

Let me tell you that this "simple" class definition may be obvious to those of you who have used OOP in Delphi for years, but to me it only provides me with hundreds of unanswered questions on what do I use and how do I use it.

To me, this does not appear to be a science. It appears to be an art of how to best structure your information into objects.

So this question, and I hope it doesn't get closed because I really need help with this, is where or how do I get the best instruction on using Delphi to create classes - and how to do it the proper Delphi way.

Comment: Your code using a record looks fine to me.

Comment: If you are not well versed in OOP yet, I would not dive straight into using generics. Generics and things like meta classes are concepts that take some "adjusting to". Not saying that you should stay away from generics. Not at all. But give yourself a chance at "plain" OOP first. Perhaps in a couple of trial projects. When you have created your own TObject descendants and TObjectList (the plain not the generic one) descendants and have written the code to get at the instances in the lists in a type safe manner a couple of times, you will start to get a feel for what is in the generics classes.

Comment: @David: That's just code copied from Generics.Collections, so it better look fine. But I have a zillion questions in trying to apply it to the needs of my own data structure that inherits from TList<T>.

Comment: @Marjan: Using Generics is not a problem. In fact, using objects and classes are not a problem. It's in the creating the objects I need, which (in this case) is an extension to a Generic object. Yes, I can start simple. But I'm working with an existing mature application of mine, and this was the particular structure that was suggested should be made a class. I do appreciate your idea of starting simply, though. The point is, Delphi has not made it simple to educate ones self as to what they need to talk the Delphi OOP fluently.

Comment: In that case: I'd study sample code from other projects. The hard part will be finding code examples for some kind of real world app as most open source Delphi projects are libraries and frameworks that have nothing to do with domain stuff such as people, cars, employees, etc. One source of information I can recommend is Martin Fowler's catelogue of enterprise application architecture patterns. It will give you plenty to ponder about class design regardless of language. See: http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/ and http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/

Comment: @Marjan: I'm afraid your links don't make it any simpler. :-(

Comment: You can check out [Generic collections library for Delphi](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-coll/). It contains many structured list variants using generics.

Comment: Understandable :-) Class design is one of the hardest activities in development. And one of the hardest to talk about, because it almost always "depends". Google on `SOLID principles`. That will bring up a list of resources that should give you some very useful guidelines for designing your classes and should get your OOP thinking started.

Comment: Zarco Gajic hosts an online Delphi OOP course written by John Barrow, [Learning Object Oriented Programming with Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/course/a/oop_intro.htm).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> To me, this does not appear to be a science. It appears to be an art
>   of how to best structure your information into objects.

Well... Yeah. There really aren't a lot of formal requirements. It's really just a set of tools to help you organize your ideas, and eliminate a lot of duplication along the way.

> Then an OOP advocator will probably tell me to make this a class. Logically, I would think this would be a class inherited from the generic TList.

Actually, the whole point of generic containers is that you *don't* have to make a new container class for each type of object. Instead, you'd make a new content class and then create a `TList<TWhatever>`.

Think of a class instance as a pointers to a record.

Now: why use a class when you could use a pointer to a record? A couple reasons:

- **encapsulation**: You can hide some aspects of the implementation with the `private` keyword so that other developers (including your future self) know not to depend on implementation details that may change or that just aren't important to understanding the concept.
- **polymorphism**: You can avoid a lot of special dispatch logic by giving each of your records a set of pointers to functions. Then, rather than having a large `case` statement where you do different things for each type of object, you loop through your list and send each object the same message, then it follows the function pointer to decide what to do.
- **inheritance**: As you start making records with pointers to functions and procedures, you find that you often have cases where you need a new function-dispatch record that's very much like one you already have, except you need to change one or two of the procedures. Subclassing is just a handy way to make that happen.

So in your other post, you indicated that your overall program looks like this:

```
procedure PrintIndiEntry(JumpID: string);
  var PeopleIncluded : TList<...>;
begin      
   PeopleIncluded := result_of_some_loop;
   DoSomeProcess(PeopleIncluded);
end;
```

It's not clear to me what `Indi` or `JumpID` mean, so I'm going to pretend that your company does skydiving weddings, and that `Indi` means "individual" and `JumpID` is a primary key in a database, indicating a flight where all those individuals are in the wedding party and scheduled to jump out of the same plane... And it's vitally important to know their `Relationship` to the happy couple so that you can give them the right color parachute.

Obviously, that isn't going to match your domain exactly, but since you're asking a general question here, the details don't really matter.

What the people in the other post were trying to tell you (my guess anyway) wasn't to replace your list with a class, but to replace the JumpID with one.

In other words, rather than passing `JumpID` to a procedure and using that to fetch the list of people from a database, you create a `Jump` class.

And if your JumpID actually indicates a jump as in `goto`, then you'd probably actually a bunch of classes that all subclass the same thing, and override the same method in different ways.

In fact, let's assume that you do some parties that aren't weddings, and in that case, you don't need the Relationships, but only a simple list of people:

```
type TPassenger = record
   FirstName, LastName: string;
end;

type TJump = class
  private
    JumpID   : string;
    manifest : TList< TPassenger >;
  public
    constructor Init( JumpID: string );
    function GetManifest( ) : TList< TPassenger >;
    procedure PrintManifest( ); virtual;
end;
```

So now `PrintManifest()` does the job of your `PrintIndyEntry()`, but instead of calculating the list inline, it calls `Self.GetManifest()`.

Now maybe your database doesn't change much, and your `TJump` instance is always short lived, so you decide to just populate `Self.manifest` in the constructor. In that case, `GetManifest()` just returns that list.

Or maybe your database changes frequently, or the `TJump` sticks around long enough that the database may change underneath it. In that case, `GetManifest()` rebuilds the list each time it's called... Or perhaps you add another `private` value indicating the last time you queried, and only update after the information expires.

The point is that `PrintManifest` doesn't have to care how `GetManifest` works, because you've hidden that information away.

Of course, in Delphi, you could have done the same thing with a `unit`, hiding a list of cached passenger lists in your `implementation` section.

But clasess bring a little more to the table, when it comes time to implement the wedding-party-specific features:

```
type TWeddingGuest = record
  public
    passenger    : TPassenger;
    Relationship : string;
end;

type TWeddingJump = class ( TJump )
  private
    procedure GetWeddingManifest( ) : TList< TWeddingGuest >;
    procedure PrintManifest( ); override;
end;
```

So here, the `TWeddingJump` inherits the `Init` and `GetManifest` from the `TJump`, but it also adds a `GetWeddingManifest( );`, and it's going to override the behavior of `PrintManifest()` with some custom implementation. (You know it's doing this because of the `override` marker here, which corresponds to the `virtual` marker in `TJump`.

But now, suppose that `PrintManifest` is actually a rather complicated procedure, and you don't want to duplicate all that code when all you want to do is add one column in the header, and another column in the body listing the relationship field. You can do that like so:

```
type TJump = class
   // ... same as earlier, but add:
   procedure PrintManfestHeader(); virtual;
   procedure PrintManfiestRow(passenger:TPassenger); virtual;
end;
type TWeddingJump = class (TJump)
   // ... same as earlier, but:
   // * remove the PrintManifest override
   // * add:
   procedure PrintManfestHeader(); override;
   procedure PrintManfiestRow(passenger:TPassenger); override;

end;
```

Now, you want to do this:

```
procedure TJump.PrintManifest( )
   var passenger: TPassenger;
begin;
   // ...
   Self.PrintManifestHeader();
   for guest in Self.GetManifest() do begin
      Self.PrintManifestRow();
   end;
   // ...
end;
```

But you can't, yet, because `GetManifest()` returns `TList< TPassenger >;` and for `TWeddingJump`, you need it to return `TList< TWeddingGuest >`.

Well, how can you handle that?

In your original code, you have this:

```
IndiPtr: pointer
```

Pointer to what? My guess is that, just like this example, you have different types of individual, and you need them to do different things, so you just use a generic pointer, and let it point to different kinds of records, and hope you cast it to the right thing later. But classes give you several better ways to solve this problem:

- You could make `TPassenger` a class and add a `GetRelationship()` method. This would eliminate the need for `TWeddingGuest`, but it means that `GetRelationship` method is always around, even when you're not talking about weddings.
- You could add a `GetRelationship(guest:TPassenger)` in the `TWeddingGuest` class, and just call that inside `TWeddingGuest.PrintManifestRow()`.

But suppose you have to query a database to populate that information. With the two methods above, you're issuing a new query for each passenger, and that might bog down your database. You really want to fetch everything in one pass, in `GetManifest()`.

So, instead, you apply inheritance again:

```
type TPassenger = class
  public
    firstname, lastname: string;
end;
type TWeddingGuest = class (TPassenger)
  public
    relationship: string;
end;
```

Because `GetManifest()` returns a list of passengers, and all wedding guests are passengers, you can now do this:

```
type TWeddingJump = class (TJump)
  // ... same as before, but:
  // replace: procedure GetWeddingManfiest...
  // with:
  procedure GetManifest( ) : TList<TPassenger>; override;
  // (remember to add the corresponding 'virtual' in TJump)
end;
```

And now, you fill in the details for `TWeddingJump.PrintManifestRow`, and the same version of `PrintManifest` works for both `TJump` and `TWeddingJump`.

There's still one problem: we declared `PrintManifestRow(passenger:TPassenger)` but we're actually passing in a `TWeddingGuest`. This is legal, because `TWeddingGuest` is a subclass of `TPassenger`... But we need to get at the `.relationship` field, and `TPassenger` doesn't have that field.

How can the compiler trust that inside a `TWeddingJump`,  you're always going to pass in a `TWeddingGuest` rather than just an ordinary `TPassenger`? You have to assure it that the `relationship` field is actually there.

You can't just declare it as `TWeddingJupmp.(passenger:TWeddingGuest)` because by subclassing, you're basically promising to do all the things the parent class can do, and the parent class can handle *any* `TPassenger`.

So you could go back to checking the type by hand and casting it, just like an untyped pointer, but again, there are better ways to handle this:

- **Polymorphism approach:** move the `PrintManifestRow()` method to the `TPassenger` class (removing the `passenger:TPassenger` parameter, as this is now the implicit parameter `Self`), override that method in `TWeddingGuest`, and then just have `TJump.PrintManifest` call `passenger.PrintManifestRow()`.
- **Generic class approach:** make `TJump` itself a generic class (type `TJump<T:TPassenger> = class`), and instead of having `GetManifest()` return a `TList<TPassenger>`, you have it return `TList<T>`. Likewise, `PrintManifestRow(passenger:TPassenger)` becomes `PrintManifestRow(passenger:T)`;. Now you can say: `TWeddingJump = class(TJump<TWeddingGuest>)` and now you're free to declare the overridden version as `PrintManifestRow(passenger:TWeddingGuest)`.

Anyway, that's way more than I expected to write about all this. I hope it helped. :)

Comment: Thank you, @tangentstorm for that very amusing interpretation of my routine. No, it's not for planning skydiving for weddings, but maybe that's a niche I should explore. :-) Actually, it's for genealogy and the Indi's are individuals and the JumpID is a string to represent a specific Indi, but it is called JumpID because it is used as a hyperlink you click on to get to the indi. It might better be called IndiID.

Comment: What you are basically saying is that I should elevate my objects to high level entities such as my Indis. Then I can provide procedures that operate on Indis and hide the unnecessary details. I understand all that. So then I add an Event object. Then I need to somehow associate Events to Indis. Then I add a Relationship object. Now I have relationships between 2 Indis. Relationships between 3 or more Indis. Events associated with a Relationship. Let's add Places as an object as well. I've got all of this programmed into my mature genealogy program. How do I convert this all to classes?

Comment: Well, you don't need to convert it all at once... Or at all. But for starters, look for places where you're doing dispatch based on the type of a record, and turn those records into classes. Look for functions that all seem to deal with the same type, and see if they work better as methods of a class. You can use class instances anywhere you use records, and they play nice together. In the example above, I was trying to show how you could make a lot of little restructurings without shaking things up all at once. That's pretty much how I'd do it in real life, too.

Comment: That makes sense to me. It is the essense of programming to "make a lot of little restructurings without shaking things up all at once". The cardinal rule is to always keep your program working while you make enhancements. Never break it. Convert it piece by piece.