# Memory profiling of C# application with COM

Tags: c#, delphi, com, profiling

Are there any tools for memory profiling of applications that consist of `C#` and `Delphi` parts?

These two parts cannot be started separately - its one Application. `C#` and `Delphi` communicate via `COM` with each others.

*Update*
I have tried `dotTrace Memory 3.5` - application crashed with Exception in `clr.dll.` I can start the application via profiler - choice *Mark Memory* -  the crash occur if I want to get a snapshot.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? How would a correct solution look like? For example, on the Delphi side, what are you looking for: graphics of allocations and deallocations of memory vs time? Reports of leaked memory? How about the .net side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/291631/62576 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10644/62576

Comment: @CosminPrund - correct is any solution with the opprortunity for me to profile memory of my application. "Gaphics of allocations and deallocations" will be ok.

Answer (score 4):

I assume  you compile them separately, which means that they can be profiled separately.  Depending on your version of delphi, AQTime comes with it for gross profiling from the debugger.

I can't really help with the C# portion, but I assume profilers exist, perhaps in Microsofts own tool chain, that can also be run from the IDE.

Comment: +1 - they may a single application communicating via COM but they still have different memory management systems and so need profiling separately

Comment: @Justin - "they may a single application communicating via COM" thats true. "they still have different memory management systems and so need profiling separately" How can I profile C# part separately if I cannot start it separately?

Comment: @Gregor Brandt - the same comment as for Justin ) - How can I profile C# part separately if I cannot start it separately?

Comment: give you +1 for the  try to help me )

Comment: @MikroDel Just profile it as you would any other C# application.  Ideally you will be able to attach both profilers to the same application at the same time, however in reality you are probably going to have to run the same application twice and try to perform the same steps each time.

Comment: @Justin - I have updated my question - application crash is the result if I try to profile it with dotTrace Memory 3.5

Comment: @MikroDel If you are having a problem with a specific memory profiler then it might be best to ask a separate question (or raise it with the vendors of that software) as otherwise this question kind of becomes a moving target

Comment: @Justin - my question is what I want to know - "Memory profiling of C# application with COM". After I have got some answers - I have tried to use some advices from this answers. So I dont see it as the "moving target" problem

Answer (score 1):

dotTrace Memory or Scitech memory profiler for .NET and AQTime or FastMM for Delphi, just use them together. I don't know any integrated solution.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know that there are some memory profiles for Delphi and C# that can be found with google. My question was not about which product are there for each programming language, but how to use them in my situation.

Comment: I don't understand a problem. You just take FastMM, include it in your Delphi project, turn on required options for memory profiling. Then start dotTrace Memory and select main executable to profile (for example, if your C# part is a dll, then select Delphi .exe file). Then you just get two reports from two profilers.

Comment: give you +1 for the  try to help me )